# Winston: The error instance is not an error instance anymore

Tags: winston

I give an instance of Error into the logger:

```
console.log(error instanceof Error) // This shows true
logger.error(error)
```

But inside errors.js of the logform library `einfo` is not an instance of Error:

```
module.exports = format((einfo, { stack }) => {
  console.log(einfo instanceof Error) // This shows false
  if (einfo instanceof Error) {
  ...
```

I am not sure at what point the inserted Object becomes not an Error instance, but it prevents me from getting an error stack, even when there is one.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    ...
```

My transports settings:

```
new transports.DailyRotateFile({
    level: 'error',
    filename: 'core-errors-%DATE%.log',
    dirname: './logs',
    frequency: (config.logging.rotationInterval * 24) + 'h',
    maxFiles: config.logging.deletionInterval + 'd',
    format: format.combine(
        format.errors({ stack: true }),
        format.timestamp({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
        }),
        errorFormat
    )
})
```

And my errorFormat:

```
const errorFormat = format.printf((info) => {
    const sym = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(info).find(function(s) {
        return String(s) === "Symbol(message)";
    })

    return JSON.stringify({
        timestamp: info.timestamp, 
        level: info.level, 
        message: info.message ? info.message : sym ? info[sym] : ''
    })
})
```

The `info` parameter in my `errorFormat` is this:

```
{
  level: 'error',
  timestamp: '2022-08-04 18:07:38',
  [Symbol(level)]: 'error',
  [Symbol(message)]: '{"level":"error"}'
}
```

So, stack has not been added, because the error.js in the logform library hasn't recgonized the error instance.

How does the error instance get turned into not being an instance of Error?

Winston version 3.8.1
Node version 16.13.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found, what my mistake was. You have to add `format.errors({ stack:true })` into the format property of the logger and not of the transport. The code below works for me. Maybe it helps someone else, too.

```
const logger = createLogger({
    format: format.combine(
        format.errors({ stack:true }),
        format.json()
    ),
    transports: [
      new transports.DailyRotateFile({
        level: 'error',
        filename: 'core-errors-%DATE%.log',
        dirname: './logs',
        frequency: (config.logging.rotationInterval * 24) + 'h',
        maxFiles: config.logging.deletionInterval + 'd',
        format: format.combine(
            format.timestamp({
                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
            }),
            errorFormat
        )
      })
    ]
})
```